# 'chatterbot' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, python-3.x, nlp, chatterbot

I just clone the `chatterbot` api and tried to run the `django_app` from examples as `python manage.py runserver`. I'm facing this issue. `'chatterbot' is not a registered namespace`
Can any one explain the error and what should I do?

**app.html:**

```
 var chatterbotUrl = '{% url "chatterbot:chatterbot" %}';
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from chatterbot.ext.django_chatterbot import urls as chatterbot_urls
from example_app.views import ChatterBotAppView, ChatterBotApiView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ChatterBotAppView.as_view(), name='main'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^api/chatterbot/', ChatterBotApiView.as_view(), name='chatterbot'),
]
```

**Further info:**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
'chatterbot' is not a registered namespace
Python Version: 3.6.7
```

**Note:** I have already checked this [link](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1373) but of no use.

Comment: Did you tried what they say in the last comment? https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1373#issuecomment-422281573

Comment: Have you checked your Installed apps?

Comment: `var chatterbotUrl = '{% url "chatterbot" %}'`;  OR register in the urls.py of your chatterbot app just below the import: `app_name = 'chatterbot'.` Anyway, its always a good idea to not copy code you don't understand

Comment: @RompePC- yes, I have checked, but no use.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi- in Installed apps `'chatterbot.ext.django_chatterbot',
    'example_app',` has already added.

Comment: @Matt- i tried what you mentioned, but getting same error. I copied that for learning purpose. Once the code works on my machine, i will change code to get better understanding of the purpose of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference to others.

I was able to resolve the issue. In `nav.html` replace this 21-line i.e., `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'chatterbot:chatterbot' %}">API</a>` with `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'chatterbot' %}">API</a>`. This will sort out the issue and NO NEED TO CHANGE ANY PART OF CODE EXPECT THIS LINE, KEEP THE CODE AS IT IS CLONED.